# "Muso" and "Journo" Usage and Origin

Tags: british-english, abbreviations

I have been watching a lot of British TV recently and I hear the word "journos" for journalists and "musos" for musicians, but I don't ever hear these words in the US. From my understanding they don't *have* to be plural, i.e. "muso" might also be used, but I am no expert obviously. <s>Edit: I believe "pol" for politician is another.</s> (Pol is apparently used in AmE also)

Are there any other shortened (collective?) nouns like these in British English? Any particular reason why this isn't done in the US English?

*Edit after comments:* This question is specifically about nouns that describe a **group of people** or a **profession** that are shortened. "Profs" might be one example that is used in AmE, though I don't hear it often, and it doesn't have the same -o ending.

Comment: At least one of the contractions you cite, "pol", has a relatively wide, if informal, usage in US English, probably originating a century or so ago in Newspaper headlines.

Comment: What makes you think it's not done in American English? AmE is particularly fond of abbreviations. Off the top of my head, _peeps_, _rad_, _bull_, _lit_. What is so special about _journos_ and _musos_ that does not apply to _profs_ or _cops_ or _ammo_?

Comment: @terdon: What is special about those two is that they don't appear in AmE. No pattern that I can tell (maybe ending in -o'?).

Comment: @Mitch I know, I'm just having trouble understanding how the OPs examples are any different than the hundreds of abbreviations and acronyms commonly used in AmE. I mean that the question "Any particular reason why this isn't done in the US English?" seems based on a flawed premise.

Comment: @terdon The examples I am talking about concern labels specifically for **groups of people** or **professions** that are shortened versions of a longer word. I rarely hear "Profs" in AmE but that might be regional. Cops isn't (as far as I know) short for a longer word for police. AmE is, as you state, fond of abbreviations, but not the ones I cited for some reason. I agree with brasshat that it might have started with newspaper headlines because that's the place I've most frequently seen these abbreviations but I'm not sure, hence the question.

Comment: In that case, please [edit] your question and clarify what you find strange about those particular abbreviations. Cops [is actually](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=cop&allowed_in_frame=0) a contraction of _coppers_ so it would apply. You also have _docs_, _vets_, sales _reps_, _sarges_, _VPs_, the _veep_, _POTUS_ and I'm sure there are many more. I just don't see that there's any difference between AmE and BrE here. Only that some terms are more common on one side of the pond or the other. The phenomenon itself seems to be quite international.

Comment: It seems like the British tabloids are particularly fond of the -o ending.  I remember they used to call Michael Jackson "Jacko," which was almost never used here in America.

Comment: In AusE there are loads of diminutives like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to John Ayto & John Simpson, *The Oxford Dictionary of Modern Slang* (1992), both *journo* and *muso* originated in Australia. Here the dictionary's entries for the two terms:

> **journo** *noun orig Austral* A journalist, esp. a newspaper journalist. 1967—. **TIMES** *Journos who work with the written word are seldom at ease with spoken English* (1985). [Shortened from *journalist* + *-o*.]
>
> ...
>
> **muso** *noun orig Austral* A musician, esp. a professional one. 1967–. K. GILBERT I used to be a muso and a hustler from the city but I'm a tribal man too (1977). [From *musician* + *-o*.]

Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, eighth edition (1984) doesn't have an entry for *muso*, but it dates *journo* to circa 1940:

> **journo.** A journalist: Aus.: since ca. 1940. (B.P) The almost ubiquitous Aus. -o, taken over—in part, at least—from Cockney immigrants.

Partridge's remark about the "almost ubiquitous Aus. *-o*" suffix corroborates curiousdannii's comment beneath the OP's question that "In AusE there are loads of diminutives like this."

A couple of booklets from the National Museum of Australia—*Aussie English for Beginners* (2002) and *Aussie English or beginners Book Two* (2003)—identify several other *-o* slang terms used in Australia: *arvo* (afternoon), *bizzo* (business), *compo* (worker's compensation payment), *garbo* (garbage collector), *rego* (motor vehicle registration), and *smoko* (smoking break). Both *bizzo* and *garbo* seem to meet the OP's specific request for "other shortened (collective?) [occupational] nouns like these."

Answer (score 0):

The '-o' ending is very common in English usage, even when it doesn't necessarily shorten the word (yobbos instead of yobs, for example).

I can't be sure why this is, but for some reason I'm thinking it's something to do with the kind of slang used in upper class prep schools and public (by which they really mean private/exclusive/fee-paying) schools like Eton, where nicknames are an important indicator of social acceptance but often aren't meant to be insulting or demeaning (because the school is full of future industry leaders and politicians, it doesn't do to anger a classmate who might be in charge of you one day!). Because of this, they're often based on surnames - longer ones would be contracted but shorter ones are lengthened to give them two syllables, which sounds catchier. Keats, for example, becomes Keatsy or Keatso; Cameron becomes Camo and so on.

I know it seems tenuous and I'm sorry I can't think of the source for this or where I got it from! There would certainly be plenty of future 'journos' and 'musos' among the ranks at these schools, anyway...

Comment: If all you'd written was the first paragraph I would've upvoted it...